# Swfit how to initialize a variable with promise?

Tags: swift

I have a viewModel which gets user profile via API call. I want to set the variable in viewModel so that I can make use of the variable in elsewhere. The code is as follows:

```
class UserProfileViewModel {

   let userId: String

   private let getUserProfile: GetUserProfile

   init(getUserProfile = GetUserProfile()) {
       self.getUserProfile = getUserProfile
       updateData()
    }

func updateData() {
    getUserProfile.start().done {
        [weak self] userProfile in
        guard let userProfile = userProfile else { return }
        // Should assign the userProfile.id to self.memberId
    }
}
```

it returns this errro to me `Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties`

I need to initialize the public variable in the init, but the actual data is obtained from API call, is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Make it optional (and update all dependent code), like

```
class UserProfileViewModel {

   var userId: String?
...
```